# How to link a React Progressive Web App (PWA) to a firebase database?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, progressive-web-apps

As of now, I have successfully updated my data by manually making changes in firebase database and displaying it out in real time on my PWA. 
But now I wish to write/ insert data into the Firebase Realtime Database and simultaneously display the changes.

My question is, how do we push data from a React WebApp to the firebase realtime database?

Answer (score 1):

take a look a [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write) these are the official docs.

you need to start your application (with you own application data)

```
 var config = {
    apiKey: "apiKey",
    authDomain: "projectId.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://databaseName.firebaseio.com",
    storageBucket: "bucket.appspot.com"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);

  // Get a reference to the database service
  var database = firebase.database();
```

then you can instantiate and operate using the expose sdk methods

```
var database = firebase.database();
var starCountRef = firebase.database().ref('posts/' + postId + '/starCount');
starCountRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
  updateStarCount(postElement, snapshot.val());
});
```

Source: the official docs